# -f pretty for steak

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bdd, ruby-1.9.2

I want to see all the steps for steak, like when I do `cucumber features -f pretty` for `cucumber` it shows all the passing, failing and undefined steps. Similarly in `rspec` it is `-f nested`. Is there any command in case of steak? In certain cases the steak does not show which line gave error. For instance: I have a variable `post` and I use `@post` by mistake. In this case, it is very difficult to detect where is the error. I am using `debugger` and doing `n` until an exception is raised. I hope there is other idea to detect the error, because detecting my error with `debugger` in this case is really tiresome. I hope my question is clear.